# Why scp from remote to local changes filenames with umlauts?

Tags: utf-8, filenames, scp

I was copying a webspace from remote to local with

```
scp -r account@remote-server.de:html /path/to/copy/
```

The problem: filenames with umlauts changed, e.g. remote: hörsaal.jpg  / local: hÃ¶rsaal.jpg

locale on remote server:

```
# locale
LANG=de_DE.utf8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.utf8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8
```

on local server:

```
# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

As I copy the output I see that LC_ALL is empty on local server.
Is that the reason for the problem?
BTW. I tried

```
convmv  -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8  hÃ¶rsaal.jpg
```

The response (a part):
`Skipping, already UTF-8: hÃ¶rsaal.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do the conversion on the host system?

```
convmv  -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 hörsaal.jpg
```

And then do the transfer to the target system:

```
scp -r account@remote-server.de:html /path/to/copy/
```

***Remark** I suppose the source system has ISO-8859-1 as default file encoding and the target system uses UTF-8 as file encoding*

**Workaround**

Rename the file on the host machine, so it no longer contains the *ISO-8859-1* specific characters. Copy it to the target machine.

Comment: I'm not able to run convmv on the host system. I'm not the administrator of this system, so I cannot install it. BTW, it's a productive system - I wouldn't like to make changes on the host. I think you are right with your remark. The source system is quite old.

Comment: Your workaround would break the system as there are references on the files in the database.

Comment: Then make a copy of the file on the host system, rename it and copy it to the target system. If the full system gets cloned to the new target system, rename it back with the special characters in it, then they will be in UTF-8 format.

Comment: This last remoark is not clear from the question. Add some __why / background__ about _why this quesiton is asked!_

Comment: Okay, to clarify: it's a quite big (> 4 GB)  and a couple of years old TYPO3 Installation which I have to clone on my development server for a complete relaunch. So renaming manually would be really a lot of work. Maybe I have to think about a script which do that work on both servers.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sence! Indeed when there are many files, on the system, then better write a small script, make default conversion, like all `ö` to `oe`, `ü` to `ue`, etc. So all files with different ISO characters can be handled in one run. And be back converted to their original character on the target system (`oe` back to `ö`, etc).